# Apply own function to each element without loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I get some trouble. 
I have matrices

```
f=magic(5)
h=magic(5)
g=magic(5)
```

wand with them I need to do following algorithm:

```
for x=1:size(f,1)
  for y=1:size(f,2)
     fp=f;
     fp(x,y)=fp(x,y)+a;
     Q(x,y)=sum(sum(conv2(fp,h,'same')-g));
  end
end
```

How can I avoid nested loops? Thought about arrayfun, but get no idea now to apply it in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't `fp=f` at the very start?

Comment: I need to change only one element of matrix and compute Q. Then return it value back and do the same with another element

Comment: Note that `arrayfun` is just a wrapper for for loops with more overhead, it is not a form of verctorization

Comment: What are your actual datasizes for f, g, h?

Comment: You are saying the kernel `h` is of size `2000x 2000`? Wow!

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the loop? If you're worried about performance, and your real arrays are larger than in the example, you may want to look at replacing the convolution with the Fourier transform.

To make it easier for Matlab to optimize the loop, you can replace the double loop with a single loop:

```
Q = zeros(size(f)); %# preallocation is important
for idx=1:numel(f)
     fp=f;
     fp(idx)=fp(idx)+a;
     Q(idx)=sum(sum(conv2(fp,h,'same')-g));
  end
end
```

If you really want a solution with `arrayfun`, you can use an indicator function for adding `a` to the right element. Note that this becomes a lot harder to read (and therefore to maintain) than the loop solution.

```
idxMat = reshape(1:numel(f),size(f));
Q = arrayfun(@(x)sum(sum(conv2(f+double(idxMat==x)*a,h,'same')-g)), idxMat);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try your suggestions. Also it seems to me that my code can be computed in parallel, because each element perturbation is independent. But I don't know the syntax for this (((

Comment: For parallelization you need the parallel computing toolbox, and then it's as easy as replacing `for` in my solution with `parfor`. What you should really do, tough, is replace the convolution with the fourier transform, which should give you at least an order of magnitude of speed increase.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You could do</strike>

```
fp = arrayfun(@(x)x+a, f);
```

but the point about `Q(x,y)` seems unclear to me. Its values are equal for all `x` and `y`, are't they?

Only now I come to understand the thing. No, I don't think this is easily feasible with an `arrayfun()` call, you are probably stuck on using the loop.

You could, of course, build up an array with all the coordinates needed such as `{[1 1] [1 2] [1 3] ... [2 1] [2 2] [2 3]}` and perform a `cellfun()` call with it, but I doubt that this will be very handy; probably the loop is the best you can do. (And why not? There is nothing bad about nested loops...)

You could as well replace the inner loop with an `arrayfun()` call, such as

```
for x=1:size(f,1)
  Q(x,:) = arrayfun(@(y)treat_element(f,x,y), 1:size(f,2))
end

function q=treat_element(f,x,y)
    fp=f
    fp(x,y)=fp(x,y)+a
    q=sum(sum(conv2(fp,h,'same')-g));
end
```

(untested!), but I don't think that will be better than your original code.

Comment: my mistake, Q(x,y)=sum(sum(conv2(fp,h,'same')-g));

Comment: Thank you. The bad of my code is that it is very slow with big matrices, so I was trying to simplify it. Also I have an idea to compute it on GPU, but actually I'm newbie in this field.